# show data in execution time vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I´m trying to do a form that fill a table with data from laravel API. For build all my app vue i´m using vue js 3 and composition API. As i say, i need that when i clicked my button fill my table with data from my form. To do this, in my button i have a @click function `@click="searchRegisters()">` searchRegister it´s my function that call my anonymous function in composable that contains a axios post and return data. My data it´s very long, but for example...

```
{"data":[{"id":895,"name":"Aguilera Muriel Fatimas","address":"CALLE CALLEJAS, 8",
```

My composable and my call to function sending data it´s ok. My problem it´s that, in my component, nAsignedCalls included in my first component, i can´t show my data. To send this data to this component i´m using this, (my action button) function searchRegister and in this function:

```
context.emit("registers", getRegisters(toRef(param_search,'param_search')))
```

in my `setup()` i have context and i defined personaliced emit `const emitMyEvent = (event) => emit('registers', event);`

getRegister it´s my anonymous function in composable that i´m returning:

```
const getRegisters = async (param_search) => {
        var keys = Object.values(param_search);

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("parameter", keys[0].parameter); // this should be your image
        formData.append("value", keys[0].value); // it is the slug*/
        let response = await axios.post('/api/listingApi/getRegister', formData, {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}) 
        registers.value = response.data.data
    }
```

in my component `nAsignedCalls` i have in `export default defineComponent` definition emits `emits: ['registers'],` and my event

```
// personaliced event
const emitMyEvent = (event) => emit('registers', event);
```

i have a return with:

```
return { 
       remove,
       searchId,
       searchName,
       searchPhone,
       edit,
       getResults,
       getPage,
       emitMyEvent,
       getRegisters,
       registers,
 }
```

and in my template i have a v-for to get all data and construct tbody:

```
<tbody>
            <template v-for="item of registers"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ (item.name) ? item.name : '' }} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.address) ? item.address : ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{ (item.province) ? item.province : ''}} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.city) ? item.city : ''}} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.cp) ? item.cp : ''}} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.phone) ? item.phone : ''}} </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="text-light" :class="item.status.class_span">
                            {{ (item) ? item.status.name : 'null' }}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="hover-text">
                            <div class="icon-actions">
                                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-1">   
                                        <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container-actions">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <button class="tooltip-text btn" id="edit" @click="edit(item.id)"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-edit"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
```

My problem it´s that i have my data in network tab ok, but i don´t know how i can´t show in my table or send ok to my table... I´m something noob in vuejs 3 but i´m reading very much documentation...

**UPDATE**

i can show that if assign result to my ref, i have a promise. i´m doing, in my call function then():

```
getRegisters(toRef(param_search,'param_search')).then(response => this.register_data = response)

console.log(this.register_data)
```

but now console return blank line...

Thanks for readme and help me. Sorry for my bad english so.

Comment: And where is `this.register_data` defined? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: @Tolbxela this.register_data it´s defined in props in my principal component

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get some data and show it in the table, then you don't need any events.

**UPDATE**

It doesn't really matter where you data is. You can put it in a composable or Pinia store.

Here is a basic example

```js
const { createApp, ref, onMounted } = Vue 

const useStore = () => {
  const posts = ref([])
  const getData = () => {
    posts.value = []
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) =>  posts.value = data)
  }   
  return { posts, getData }
}

const Blog = {
  props: ['posts'],
  template: '#blog'
}

const App = {
  components: { Blog },
  setup() {    
    const { posts, getData } = useStore()    
    onMounted( () => getData());
    return { posts, getData }  
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
label { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<button @click="getData()">reload</button><br/>
<blog :posts="posts"></blog>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="blog">
<div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
  <label>Id:</label>&nbsp; {{post.id}}<br/>
  <label>Title:</label>&nbsp; {{post.title}}<br/>
  <label>Body:</label>&nbsp; {{post.body}}<br/>
  <hr/>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But my method getRegister it´s in composable and i need to senda data from my form. Receibed data from my API i need return and send to my other component. and in this component a need draw it

Comment: I've changed the sample to the Composition API

Comment: i know witch it´s my problem. when i send my form, my data it´s ok in network tab, but if i do console.log for my prop that i assigned result call my functio getRegisters i can show in console, that return Promise {<pending>} and i can´t access to data

Comment: Sure, since your `getRegisters` is `async`, you have to call it with `await`!  Like this: `context.emit("registers", await getRegisters( toRef(param_search,'param_search') ) )`.
I have overseen it before.

Comment: i´m sorry for my ignorance... i´m trying to learn. i did that you say me... but my form not show anything and in console neither. i don´t find my response in nowhere